# Having Column Header in All pages - Telerik Report Viewer

Tags: telerik, reportviewer, telerik-reporting

I am trying to show a report using telerik report viewer. I have one problem with this. The Header Name for all columns are displaying only in first page . How can i make visible in all pages.

Answer (score 2):

Put the headers in the groupheader section. not in the detal section

Answer (score 2):

Set the property ColumnHeadersPrintOnEveryPage to "true", default is "false".